# MailApp: Dynamic variables in CC and BCC mail is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automated emails.
I have a query in google sheets that displays me all cases where an email has to be sent. The for loop collects the corresponding customer name, email, VIN, telephone etc.. The subject and body of the email replaces {name}, {VIN} etc. with the correct data from the google sheet. This works so far, but when I put someone in CC or BCC the variables don't change for the CC or BCC email.
The output in the subject is empty and in the email body it is displayed with {name} etc. instead the correct customer name.

The mails to the CC/BCC should also display the right variables, how can I fix this.

Here is my code:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  
  var scriptInfo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("script_info");
  var scriptInfoMail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("script_info_MAIL");
  var lr = scriptInfo.getLastRow();
  var templateText = scriptInfoMail.getRange(5,2).getValue();
  
  
  //get attachments
  var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Logistics2.0");
  var folder = folderIter.next();
  var file1Iter = folder.getFilesByName("Übergabeprotokoll.pdf");  
  var file1 = file1Iter.next();
  var file2Iter = folder.getFilesByName("....._03.pdf");  
  var file2 = file2Iter.next();
  
  
    for (var i = 2; i<=lr;i++){
      
      //loops through open Deal_IDs for personal info
      var currentDealId = scriptInfo.getRange(i, 1).getValues();
      var currentCustomerEmail = scriptInfo.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
      var currentEmEmail = scriptInfo.getRange(i, 12).getValue();
      var currentTelefon = scriptInfo.getRange(i, 6).getValues();
      var currentVIN = scriptInfo.getRange(i, 7).getValues();
      var currentDateEta = scriptInfo.getRange(i, 8).getDisplayValue();
      var currentName = scriptInfo.getRange(i, 10).getValues();
      var currentAbholNR = scriptInfo.getRange(i, 11).getValues();
      
      //email Subject and Body
      var subjectLine = "Anlieferung VEHICULUM-Fahrzeug VIN: " + currentVIN + " / " + currentDealId;
      
      var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("htmlTemplate") // Generate the HTML
      .getContent();
      
      var messageBody = htmlTemplate.replace(/{VIN}/g, currentVIN) //replaces VIN
      .replace(/{Name}/g, currentName) //replaces Customer Name
      .replace(/{ETA EM}/g, currentDateEta) //replaces ETA Euromaster
      .replace(/{KundenEmail}/g, currentCustomerEmail) //replaces Customer Email
      .replace(/{Telefon}/g, currentTelefon) //replaces Customer Telephone
      .replace(/{Abholnummer Kunde}/g, currentAbholNR); //replaces Abholnummer
      
       Logger.log(messageBody);
      
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: currentEmEmail, 
        subject: subjectLine, 
        htmlBody: messageBody, 
        cc: "p........@......",
        attachments: [file1, file2]});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your CC is being hardcoded by the looks of this, are you sure you're setting this from the sheet? Also it appears that your `MailApp.sendEmail()` method signature isn't correct for using advanced options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use the `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` method with the BCC and CC in the `options` parameter.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation:

> `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`
>
> Sends an email message with optional arguments.

And in the Advanced parameters section:

> `bcc  String`: a comma-separated list of email addresses to BCC
>
> `cc   String`: a comma-separated list of email addresses to CC

#### Code Modification:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: currentEmEmail, 
        subject: subjectLine, 
        htmlBody: messageBody, 
        cc: "p........@......",
        attachments: [file1, file2]});
```

Should be:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, {
  cc: "p........@......",
  name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
  attachments: [file1, file2]
});
```

#### References:

- [Class MailApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly the changes didn't work for me. I adjusted the MailApp with the additiona options from the code you provided, but the CC mails still come back with the empty parameters.
E.g.: in the mail it is displayed "Name: Customer Name" and in the CC mail it is "Name: ", with just a blank field.

Comment: How are you setting your CC parameter?

Comment: So far the CC is always the same Email addresse. Do I need to create another message body for the CC mail?

Comment: No, you can still use the CC in the same method. But from your code you are setting your CC directly, hard coded, why do you expect it to change? Can you show the code which sets your cc?

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean. I will try to fix it :) Thank you very much, hopefully I can fix it by myself.