# Use of cc and/or bcc in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am wondering how can I include a cc email in this script. Below is part of my current code. Thank you.

'''
*/

```
htmlsheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(message);
htmlsheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(JSON.stringify(obj));
if (confirm == "Yes" && EmailSent != "Email Sent") { 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {
    htmlBody: message,
    replyTo: replyTo,
    name: name_shown
  });
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue("Email Sent");
}
```

}
}
'''

Comment: Have you searched the documentation? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: This thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62919182/7108653